# simple mod_rewrite q...is the solution simple too?

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I've looked at many examples here and all over the internet, but I can't seem to find an answer I understand, or that accurately solves my problem.  I'm looking to implement a mod_rewrite directive in an .htaccess file that renames a folder to another name but does not show the name in the url bar.

For example (the user clicks a link that directs them to):

```
theSite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

I want them to see (same as above)

```
theSite.com/folder1/folder2/folder3/
```

But I want the browser to silently function in this directory

```
theSite.com/folder1/some_other_folder/folder3/
```

I am a PHP developer, writing my first web application.  I can configure apache, PHP, mysql and use them like a pro.  I'm sorry, but I don't understand the syntax for mod_rewrite.  I can't seem to grasp it despite looking at many tutorials as I would need to ask questions before I could move onto the next concept.  Thank you for your patience.

Comment: Thanks for being clear about what the user should see. That's pretty uncommon for these questions.

Comment: Is `folder3` dynamic, or always the same?

Comment: Thank you for your response.  Folder3 is dynamic and can also contain subfolders.  I'm about to implement your answers - thank you so much for taking the time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your case is pretty run-of-the-mill.  You just need to match the static string, plus a `(.*)` to match everything that follows it and store it into `$1`, then substitue `some_other_folder`.

The `[L]` flag (and absence of the `[R]` flag) instructs Apache to rewrite internally without redirecting the browser, and to stop here without matching further rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/folder3(.*)$ folder1/some_other_folder/folder3$1 [L]
```

If `folder3` itself is part of the "dynamic" portion, that is, anything after `folder2` should be silently rewritten into `some_other_folder`, leave `folder3` out of the rule and just capture everything that follows `folder2` into `$1`.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/(.*)$ folder1/some_other_folder/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing out the checkmark.  I tried using the up arrow but didn't have enough points.  Because this next question relates so closely to the first, I thought I'd ask it here.  Is it possible to do the same to a query string where the query string will always contain f=foo, and I want a use to see f=foo, but want them directed sliently to f=bar?  (Should I ask this question another way to get the arrows and check attached?

Comment: Thanks Michael.  Question Title Is: modrewrite alter 1 element of query string - thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I would use following

```
RewriteRule /folder1/folder2/folder3/ /folder1/some_other_folder/folder3/  [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  I guess I should have specified folder3 is dynamic.  Michael answered the question.  Thanks again.